# Programmatically add UIView, assign a class, remove it, repeat with different class (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible, on a single UIViewController, to programmatically:

- add a UIView
- assign it a class
- remove the UIView
- repeat with a different class?

Something like the following pseudocode:

```
func createViewWithCustomClass(classChoice: String)
{ 
   create new UIView on mainViewController
   assign classChoice class to the UIView
}

func buttonA (_sender: UIButton) 
    remove view 
    createViewWithCustomClass(classChoice: "classA")
}

func buttonB (_sender: UIButton) 
    remove view 
    createViewWithCustomClass(classChoice: "classB")
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the reusability of the same View in different controllers? Please confirm.

Comment: The reusability of the same View on a single controller.  The controller has a lot of other stuff that may be changed and affect the contents of the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> createViewWithCustomClass(classChoice: String)
> ```

Objects are not created in this dynamic way in Swift.
You can certainly have two buttons that create instances of different classes, but you cannot embody which class you want in a *string*. You must say its name:

```
func buttonA (_sender: UIButton) {
    remove view 
    let v = ClassA()
}

func buttonB (_sender: UIButton) {
    remove view 
    let v = ClassB()
}
```

Comment: I understand that - that was just my pseudocode to describe what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well you did not make clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yea, I did - those 4 bullet points sum it up.  It should be obvious that what I put up there is pseudo-code, clearly not Swift code.  That said, you finally gave me the answer I have been looking for:  "let v = ClassA()" - a simple, single line!  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be EXTREMELY simple: just a single line: `graphView = SelectedClassName()`!

```
var graphView = UIView()

func createViewWithCustomClass(classChoice: String)
{ 
    // remove old graph
    graphView.removeFromSuperView

    // assign class
    switch selectedGraph {
        case "ClassA": graphView = ClassA()
        case "ClassB": graphView = ClassB()
        //  etc.
        default: break
    }

    // add graph 
    view.addSubview(graphView)
}

func buttonA (_sender: UIButton) 
    remove view 
    createViewWithCustomClass(classChoice: "ClassA")
}

func buttonB (_sender: UIButton) 
    remove view 
    createViewWithCustomClass(classChoice: "ClassB")
}
```

Comment: @matt: how would I accomplish the same thing if, instead of `var graphView = UIView()`, the UIView had been created in Storyboard and had an outlet `@IBOutlet var graphView: UIView!`